# Max with Having clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this database

```
Game(ID,Version,Name,Price,Color,IDDISTRIBUTION,#worker)
Distribution(ID,Name,#worker,quality)  
Istitute(ID,Name,NINCeo,City)  
Sponsor(IDGAME,IDISTITUTE,VERSIONGAME)  
Designer(NIN,name,surname,role,budget)
Project(NINDESIGNER,IDGAME,VERSIONGAME,#hours)
```

(the uppercase is for indicate the foreign keys)

I have to write in SQL this nested query:

- Select the Istitute that sponsored the max number of
  games(Name,#max_games)
- Select the Istitute that sponsored the min
  number of games(Name,#min_games)
- Select the Designer that had taken
  part at almost 10 games(NIN,#game)

(In the parenthesis are the row to select,# is the result of the COUNT query)

Comment: Learning SQL is different from learning how to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: is this home work?

Comment: Is my first question on Stack Overflow!

Comment: No,i haven't understood the application of MAX and MIN with the having clause

Comment: SO is the helping platform (If you get stuck while coding, debugging etc) more than learning from scratch. Go for the respective tutorials, you will be able to find the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check out window functions! They allow you to do fun analytics, such as who had the 3rd most number of games? Try this:

```
with counts as (
    select
    i.id
    ,i.name
    ,count(distinct g.id) as gamecount
    from istitute i
    inner join games g
    on i.id=g.id
    and i.name=g.name
    group by i.id
    ,i.name
)

select
c.id
,c.name
,RANK() over (ORDER BY c.gamecount DESC) as rank
from counts c
```

Answer (score 1):

a) For Select the Istitute that sponsored the max number of games

```
;with TempCount as (
     select  IDISTITUTE,
            count(IDGAME) As GameCount 
     from Sponsor S 
     Group by  IDGAME,IDISTITUTE
    )

    select Top  1
    T.IDISTITUTE,
    Count(T.GameCount) As  MaxGameCount
    from TempCount T 
    Group  by T.IDISTITUTE order  by Count(T.GameCount) desc
```

b) For Select the Istitute that sponsored the min number of games

```
 ;with TempCount as (
     select  IDISTITUTE,
            count(IDGAME) As GameCount 
     from Sponsor S 
     Group by  IDGAME,IDISTITUTE
    )

    select Top  1
    T.IDISTITUTE,
    Count(T.GameCount) As  MinGameCount
    from TempCount T 
    Group  by T.IDISTITUTE order  by Count(T.GameCount) asc
```

Comment: where's the foreign key? The Sponsor Table have foreign keys to Game and Istitute table,so how you can count the number of games?

Answer (score 0):

I think that i've found the solution:

```
a)SELECT Name,#max_game
  FROM Istitute
  WHERE(SELECT COUNT (IDGAME) as #max_game
  FROM Sponsor,Game,Istitute
  WHERE(IDGAME=Game.id AND IDISTITUTE=Istitute.id AND VERSIONGAME=Game.Version))
  HAVING=(SELECT MAX COUNT (IDGAME) as #realmax_game)
  FROM Sponsor,Game,Istitute
  WHERE(IDGAME=Game.id AND IDISTITUTE=Istitute.id AND VERSIONGAME=Game.Version))
```

b) the same as a) but with MIN

```
c)SELECT Name,#game
  FROM Istitute
  WHERE(SELECT COUNT (IDGAME) as #game
  FROM Sponsor,Game,Istitute
  WHERE(IDGAME=Game.id AND IDISTITUTE=Istitute.id AND VERSIONGAME=Game.Version))
  HAVING #game<=10
```